# Add validation in the child component (Reactive Forms)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In the above Demo , I have built a reactive form with the input field inside a child component.I am trying to add new form control inside the child component and validate it inside the component itself.I am getting the following error.

> Error: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined

I am not sure what is the error and very new to the Reactive Forms.In Brief what i am trying to do is,

- Append new control to the parent form group from the child component
- Validation of the newly added control should be done inside the child component itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's hard to learn all Angular syntax.

There are several changes you should make:

1) [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#constructor()) constructor takes value as a first argument,

So instead of writing:

```
new FormControl(Validators.required)
```

you should be using something like:

```
new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
```

2) To access form group property you should use either:

```
formGroup.controls.controlName
```

or

```
formGroup.get('controlName')
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-otj5ue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**